# How to place constant at specific address with LD linker command file?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I'm developing a c application on an embedded processor with a gcc-based toolchain.  In my application I need to place a flag at a specific memory location.  I need help with the linker command file syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean with 'place a flag'? Do you have to define a C variable at a specific location, so that it can be accessed by another process? Like some kind of version information, or a boot option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your C file write something like:

```
static int flag __attribute__ ((section (".flag"))) __attribute__ ((__used__)) = 6;
```

In your custom linker script, add .flag to the desired section:

```
_flag_start = 0x00001234;

.flag _flag_start :
{
  KEEP(*(.flag)) ;
}
```

Be sure to add this on the correct place, as the location pointer can only grow The location pointer will be set to `_flag_start + [size of your flag]` after this block, meaning that all subsequent sections will be placed at that address or higher.

And of course, read and use the manual [David Grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19781663/911550) provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help parvus.  Your solution worked except for the "KEEP" directive gave me a linker error.  Perhaps it is because of the toolset I'm working with.  Once I removed it then I was in business.